# why do I need to apply the theorem to $f=\chi_{F^c}$?

Tags: real-analysis

> I want to show that 
>   $$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{m(F\cap B(r,x))}{m(B(r,x))}=1 \text{ for a.e. } x\in F \text{ and } =0 \text{ for a.e. } x\in F^c$$

My solution: I let $f=\chi_{F}$ and by Lebesgue differentiation theorem I can get the limit is 1 for a.e. $x\in F$ and $x\in F^c$. But why do I need to apply the theorem to $f=\chi_{F^c}$? And could you give an example for some $x$ and $F$, the above limit does not exist?

I feel like that apply LDT to $\chi_{F^c}$ and note that
$$m(F^c\cap B(x,r))=m((X-F)\cap B(x,r))=m(X\cap B(x,r))-m(F\cap B(x,r))$$
So $$1-\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{m(F\cap B(r,x))}{m(B(r,x))}=\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{m(F^c\cap B(r,x))}{m(B(r,x))}=1$$
for a.e. $x\in F^c$, that is,
$$\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{m(F\cap B(r,x))}{m(B(r,x))}=0$$

Comment: Without applying Lebesgue's Theorem for $f=\chi_{F^{c}}$ how do you get the second part?

Comment: @KaboMurphy Because the limit is $\chi_F(x)$ if I only apply to $\chi_F$. So it would be zero for a.e. $x\in F^C$.

Comment: I don't see your logic. If the limit is $1$ a.e. on $F$ it can be anything between $0$ and $1$ or many not even exist for $x \in F^{c}$.

Comment: @KaboMurphy I mean I apply to $\chi_{F}$ first and get the limit is $\chi_{F}(x)$. So for a.e. $x\in F$, it would be 1. Do you mean to apply to $\chi_{F^c}$ again? And the result is $\chi_{F^c}(x)$? But the limit is 1 for a.e. $x\in F^c$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a matter of applying the theorem to the characteristic function on $F$, because the theorem states that if $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ is locally integrable then $\underset{r \rightarrow 0}\lim\frac{1}{m(B_r(x))} \int_{B_r(x)} f(y) m(dy) = f(x)$ for almost all $x\in F.$ So, taking $f=\chi_F,\ x\in F$ we have

$\underset{r \rightarrow 0}\lim\frac{1}{m(B_r(x))} \int_{B_r(x)} f(y) m(dy) = \underset{r \rightarrow 0}\lim\frac{1}{m(B_r(x))} \int_{B_r(x)} \chi_F(y) m(dy) =  \underset{r \rightarrow 0}\lim\frac{m(F)\cap B_r(x)}{m(B_r(x))}=\chi_F(x)=1.$

And if $x\notin F$, the same calculation shows that this limit is zero.

For example, if $F$ is a square in $\mathbb R^2$ then you can calculate directly that the limit is $1$ for interior points, $1/4$ for the corners and $1/2$ on the open edges, i.e. the set (the boundary) on which this limit is $\textit{not}$ equal to $1$ has Lebesgue measure zero.

For an example of failure of this theorem, see Stein's book [Harmonic Analysis: Real-Variable Methods, Orthogonality, and Oscillatory Integrals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691032165).

Comment: So we do not need to apply LDT to $\chi_{E^c}$?

Comment: I don't understand your question, sorry!  $Fix$ a measurable set $F$ and $fix$  the function $f:=\chi_F.$ Then, apply this particular $f$ in the theorem to get that for almost every point $x$ in $F,\ \lim_{r\to 0} \frac{m(F\cap B(r,x))}{m(B(r,x))}=1$ and for almost every $x$ in $F^c,\ \lim_{r\to 0} \frac{m(F\cap B(r,x))}{m(B(r,x))}=0.$

Comment: So the later one, we apply the LDT? But I feel like if $x\in F^c$, the numerator is just 0 without LDT.

Comment: My question is if I need to apply LDT to $x\in F^c$ to get the result which is 0 a.e. for $x\in F^c$.

Comment: Yes, correct. $F$ and $\chi_F$ are fixed. You apply the thm to  $x\in F$ and then to $x\in F^c.$

Comment: Do you mean if apply to $\chi_{F^c}$ to get $\frac{m(F^c\cap B(r,x))}{m(B(r,x)}=1$ for a.e. $x\in F^c$. Why does imply $\frac{m(F\cap B(r,x))}{m(B(r,x)}=0$ for a.e. $x\in F^c$?

Comment: No. $F$ and $\chi$ do not change. $x$ does: Apply the thm first to $x\in F$ and then to $x\in F^c$, as in my answer.

Comment: Do you understand Kabo's comment? If the limit is 1 a.e. on F it can be anything between 0 and 1 or many not even exist for $x∈F^c$

Comment: @Matematieta I have edited my solution in question. Do you think it is right or not?